# How to Avoid RunTime Error in List(Of Enum(asByte)).AddRange(List(of Byte))

Tags: vb.net, enums

I wrote up the sample code below which reflects my dilemma:

```
Private Enum myEnum As Byte
  value_0 = 0
  value_1 = 1
  value_2 = 2
End Enum

Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Dim objList_Bytes As New List(Of Byte)

    objList_Bytes.Add(0)
    objList_Bytes.Add(1)
    objList_Bytes.Add(2)

    Dim objList_enum As New List(Of myEnum)
    objList_enum.AddRange(objList_Bytes)
End Sub
```

I keep lists of Enums in an Inventory Control program to track things such as ItemType, MakeOrBuy, etc, and these Enums are declared As Byte or maybe As Short. At different points I need to add the contents of a list(of byte) to a List (of enum(as byte)). The problem is, when I run the sample code I get this error:

**Unable to cast object of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.Byte]' to type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[Windows_Forms_Application_x64_FormException_Project1.Form1+myEnum]'.**

Is there a way to perform the AddRange as I am trying to without having to manually write up a For Loop for each list and thereby add in each individual item?

Thanks...

Answer (score 0):

Ok, turns out I answered my own question. This code is slightly inefficient but is abstract enough to work in many scenarios:

```
Public Shared Sub List_ConvertLists_Boxed(Of SourceType, DestType)(ByVal objList_SrcItems As List(Of SourceType), ByRef return_objList_DstItems As List(Of DestType))
    Dim z As Integer
    For z = 0 To objList_SrcItems.Count - 1
        return_objList_DstItems.Add(CObj(objList_SrcItems(z)))
    Next z
End Sub
```